# Why didn't the Andromeda use PSPs on the Magog Worldship?

Tags: andromeda

It's often depicted that the PSPs used by the Magog can destroy planets or even stars, as in their previous targets shown in the season 1 finale/season 2prem, or 2x06. It's shown that the PSPs can be reverse engineered and built by the technology of the Known Worlds in 2x06.

Why didn't the Andromeda adopt PSPs for her own weaponry? It would have been a colossal advantage over the Nietscheans, and she could have struck the Magog Worldship quite effectively even if the Nova Bombs proved ineffective again.